# Outlook GetItemFromID() Always Returns Null

Tags: c#, email, outlook, add-in

I'm currently developing an Add-in for MS Outlook 2010 using VS 2013. I am using the NewMailEx event handler to give me the EntryID of new email arriving.

Getting the EntryIDCollection is no issue (and I make sure it's a single EntryID before moving further), but I am unable to use the given ID to find the actual email object (using GetItemFromID()) so that I can access the new email's body. Instead, I just end up with an empty MailItem object after GetItemFromID() is called.

```
public static Outlook.NameSpace olNameSpace;
...
//EVENT: Item Received (new email arrival)
    private static void outLookApp_NewMailEx(string EntryIDCollection)
    {
        try
        {
            //THIS part is failing \/ and returning nothing
            object item = olNameSpace.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection, Type.Missing);
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = item as Outlook.MailItem;

            if (mailItem != null)
            {                    
                //access email object
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Receive mail exception: " + e);
        }
    }
```

Do I need to specify the folder for GetItemFromID() even though it's optional?

I'm open to other processes for accessing new email arrivals, but I was just using NewMailEx for the time being to have a simple running example.

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your help.

Ultimately, I couldn't get the `GetItemFromID` method to work consistently in conjunction with `NewMailEx`.

However, I do recommend implementing Eugene's recommendation here:

> https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/10/outlook-newmail-custom-solution/

This consistent scanning of folders works quite well (with 100% dependability in my experimentation). However, if you do experience any latency in using this with Outlook, I recommend increasing the sync delay time and possibly using event handlers such as `Folder.Items.ItemAdd` and `Folders.FolderAdd/FolderChange/FolderRemove` to check in between syncs.

My add-in needs to ensure quick processing of new email (for security scanning of links), so it cannot just solely wait in between syncs (in case a link is not scanned before the user reached it), which is why I recommend those other event handlers.

Thanks again,
~B-Witty

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is `GetItemFromID` that returns `null`? If there is a problem, it will raise an exception rather than return `null`. Most likely it is the next line (`Outlook.MailItem mailItem = item as Outlook.MailItem`) that returns `null` when you cast the returned object to `MailItem`.

Make sure you are not dealing with `ReportItem` or `MeetingItem` objects.

Comment: Dmitry, in my testing I strictly use email objects (by just sending emails to myself). Most of the time the object fails to work; however, sometimes I am able to get the email object (and thus its body, attributes, etc.). But this  is usually only for email objects that were already in the inbox (not freshly received) but still unread. If the email is freshly received as well as unread, then it never works.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the object olNameSpace that is not initialized. Try this:

```
private void outLookApp_NewMailEx(string EntryIDCollection)
    {
        olNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        try
        {
            //THIS part is failing \/ and returning nothing
            object item = olNameSpace.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection, Type.Missing);

            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = item as Outlook.MailItem;



            if (mailItem != null)
            {
                mailItem.Display();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Witty,

What is the actual value passed to the [GetItemFromID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869893(v=office.15).aspx) method?

> Do I need to specify the folder for GetItemFromID() even though it's optional?

No, there is no need to specify the second paramter. It is optional.

I'd suggest reading the following series of articles related to handling incoming emails in Outlook:

- [Handling NewMail, NewMailEx and ItemAdd Outlook events in .NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2008/04/25/newmail-itemadd-outlook-events/)
- [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/)
- [Outlook NewMail event: solution options](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/24/outlook-newmail-solution-options/)
- [Outlook NewMail event and Extended MAPI: C# example](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/01/outlook-newmail-extended-mapi/)
- [Outlook NewMail unleashed: writing a working solution (C# example)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/10/outlook-newmail-custom-solution/)

Comment: Eugene, I am passing EntryIDCollection from the NewMailEx handler: private static void outLookApp_NewMailEx(string EntryIDCollection){}; to GetItemFromID() with a value something like "00000000E8C98E35F093EE40B91C528D00991ECFA4222000" depending on the email.

Also, thank you. I've been reading Add-In Express's articles and it looks like I'm going to have to use their folders sync example.

Comment: Try to compare the real EntryID value and the passed one. You can use any low-level property explorer tool such as MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy. Let me know whether they are identical.

Comment: OutlookSpy and the EntryID do indeed give the same EntryID for an email.